# Webpack - can not load assets (404 - not found)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I was working with webpack 5 and hanging on a curious issue.

My assets(pictures, svgs) are not found by the dev server, but js files and css files works fine. If I remove the `outputPath: "/assets/images",` value from the image file loader(in webpack.conf), so the files are stored in the main folder and works.

So my thoughts are the asset folder is not transferred to the dev server!?

[Console Log Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRMBf.png)

I was testing around 6 hours with any config settings, documentations etc but it does not work.

Here's my webpack.conf

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
              test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
              use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.(png|mp4|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/,
              exclude: /fonts/,
              use: [
                  {
                      loader: "file-loader", 
                      options: {
                      name: '[name].[ext]',
                      outputPath: "/assets/images",
                      }
                  }
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
              exclude: /assets/,
              use: [
                  {
                      loader: "file-loader", 
                      options: {
                      name: '[name].[ext]',
                      outputPath: "/assets/fonts",
                      }
                  }
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.html$/i,
              loader: 'html-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['*', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        title: 'Project',
        template: './src/index.html',
        minify: false
      }),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false,
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "app.css"
      })
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
      filename: 'app.js',
      publicPath: ''
    },
    devServer: {
      port: 8080,
      contentBase: './dist',
      publicPath: ''
    },
    mode: "development"
  };
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "website_webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack serve"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@barba/core": "^2.9.7",
    "@lottiefiles/lottie-player": "^0.5.1",
    "gsap": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.5.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0-alpha.17",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.10.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Folder hierarchy:

[Dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iThNY.png)

It would be a pleasure if anyone can help me ;)

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I've changed the file loader(jpg, mp4,..) value to:

```
use: 'file-loader?name=./assets/images/[name].[ext]'
```

Works now.